# Extract element from object symfony2

Tags: symfony

**CODE**

```
$attempts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainHomeBundle:Clients')->findOneBy(array("mail"=>$getuser));
```

**RESULT**

```
print_r($attempts->getResetattemp());
```

*DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-06-25 02:15:30.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America )*

```
var_dump($attempts->getResetattemp());
```

*object(DateTime)#273 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-06-25 02:15:30.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(19) "America" }*

**How can filter the result for get only this?**

2015-06-25 02:15:30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the simple DateTime object. You can use `format()` method on it to format it in what you need:

```
$attempts->getResetattemp()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

To learn more about DateTime objects see documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php